# Get list of executed job on Hadoop cluster after cluster reboot

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, hadoop-yarn

I have a hadoop cluster 2.7.4 version. Due to some reason, I have to restart my cluster. I need job IDs of those jobs that were executed on cluster before cluster reboot. Command `mapred -list` provide currently running of waiting jobs details only

Comment: Check history server, if one is configured. It persists logs for all the past jobs on the cluster.

Answer (score 0):

You can see a list of all jobs on the Yarn Resource Manager Web UI.

In your browser go to http://ResourceManagerIPAdress:8088/

This is how the history looks on the Yarn cluster I am currently testing on (and I restarted the services several times):
[image: Resource Manager Web UI Application History]

See more info [here](http://hadooptutorial.info/yarn-web-ui/)